# QBroster is null and SubscriptionListener is never fired

Tags: quickblox

I am using libraries from **QuickBlox** and I am working on the friend request part. In order to add a friend and for them to accept me I need to use something called `QBRoster`. However the problem is that when I initialize
it by `QBRoster`

```
chatroster=QBChatService.getInstance()
        .getRoster(QBRoster.SubscriptionMode.mutual, subscriptionListener);
```

I get a `nullpointerexception` even though I get the authorization for my application and I create a session.
Also, even though I use the `subscriptionListener` it seems that I never get inside the implemented methods,i.e. the
listener is never fired.
Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared QbService in manifest?

like this :

```
<service
            android:name="com.quickblox.q_municate_core.service.QBService"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


        <receiver
            android:name="buddy_connect_design.connection_request.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.buddy_connect.apurvak.buddyconnectdemo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also try calling using this :

```
private class SubscriptionListener implements QBSubscriptionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void subscriptionRequested(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.e("SubscriptionRequested","Sucess! "+userId);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

                Log.e("SubscriptionRequested",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And Initialise like this

```
chatRoster = QBChatService.getInstance().getRoster(QBRoster.SubscriptionMode.manual, new SubscriptionListener());
```